# Finding the volume of the tetrahedron with vertices $(0,0,0)$, $(2,0,0)$, $(0,2,0)$, $(0,0,2)$. I get $8$; answer is $4/3$.

Tags: multivariable-calculus, solid-geometry

The following problem is from the 7th edition of the book "Calculus and Analytic Geometry Part II". It can be found in section 13.7. It is
problem number 5.

> Find the volume of the tetrahedron whose vertices are the given points:
>   $$ ( 0, 0, 0 ), ( 2, 0, 0 ), ( 0, 2, 0 ), ( 0, 0, 2 ) $$

Answer:

In this case, the tetrahedron is a parallelepiped object. If the bounds of such an object is given by the vectors $A$, $B$ and $C$ then
the area of the object is $A \cdot (B \times C)$. Let $V$ be the volume we are trying to find.
\begin{align*}
x^2 &= 6 - y^2 - z^2 \\[4pt]
A &= ( 2, 0, 0) - (0,0,0) = ( 2, 0, 0) \\
B &= ( 0, 2, 0) - (0,0,0) = ( 0, 2, 0) \\
C &= ( 0, 0, 2) - (0,0,0) = ( 0, 0, 2) \\[4pt]
V &= \begin{vmatrix}
a_1 & a_2 & a_3 \\
b_1 & b_2 & b_3 \\
c_1 & c_2 & c_3 \\
\end{vmatrix} =
\begin{vmatrix}
2 & 0 &0 \\
0 & 2 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 2\\
\end{vmatrix} \\
&= 2 \begin{vmatrix}
2 & 0 \\
0 & 2\\
\end{vmatrix} = 2(4 - 0) \\
&= 8
\end{align*}
However, the book gets $\frac{4}{3}$.

Comment: The volume of a tetrahedron is one sixth that of the corresponding parallelepiped

Comment: (Likewise, the area of a triangle is one half that of the corresponding parallelogram)

Comment: Incidentally, you didn’t need to do a cofactor expansion to compute that determinant. The determinant of any upper- or lower-triangular matrix (and so also any diagonal matrix) is just the product of the elements along the main diagonal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that the given volume is a cone with the height 2 and a right isosceles  triangle of side 2 as the base. Thus, its volume can be calculated as

$$\frac13 Area_{base} \cdot Height = \frac13 (\frac12 \cdot 2\cdot 2)2=\frac43$$

Answer (score 3):

A tetrahedron is never a parallepiped. It is a pyramid with a triangular base.

All six faces of a parallelopiped are parallelograms but a tetrahedron has only four faces and all are triangles.

In short, what you are measuring is very unlike what you were asked to measure.

Answer (score 0):

your tetrahedron is also a pyramid. with the volume of $\frac{1}{3}\cdot \frac{2\cdot 2}{2}\cdot 2=\frac{4}{3}$

Answer (score 0):

Referring to [this](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Tetrahedron.html), now you must divide it by $3!$ to get the final answer.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, because what you are really doing is finding the volume of a volume of a parallelepiped. You can also approach the problem this way:

###### height= |a|

###### and the area is given by

###### |b × c|

###### So, then you have Volume = height * area

###### Volume= |a||b × c|=|a ∙( b × c)|

###### For b: (0,2,0) – (0,0,0) = (0,2,0)

###### For c: (0,0,2) – (0,0,0) = (0,0,2)

###### b ×c=[(2x2)-(0x0),(0x0)-(0x2),(0x0)-(2x0)]=(4,0,0)

###### For a: (2,0,0) – (0,0,0) = (2,0,0)

###### ∴ Volume= a ∙( b × c)=(2x4)+(0x0)+(0x0)=8

###### The volume of tetrahedron is 1/6 that of the parallelepiped

∴ V_Tetrahedron=  (1/6) x 8=  4/3

Comment: Please use mathjax for math formatting. [Here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)'s a tutorial.

Comment: Oh I see. Thank you!